# How to compare data of tables from different databases in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

I have DB- A and B. Both the DBs have a table called 'company'.

I want to check whether both the tables are identical with their data or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could export the data from both tables (with the same `ORDER BY` clause) and compare the resulting files, or you could define a postgres_fdw foreign table that presents one table in the other database, then use `EXCEPT` to compute differences.

Comment: I am presently using what you mentioned above, looking for something more like a utility. Thanks for it.

Comment: Questions to recommend a software or tutorial are off-topic, sorry.

Comment: I am not looking for any software, but any PostgreSQL functions or something like that.